# Bug when I try to check only one cell in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, checkmark

When I check the first cell after loading – nothing happens, I’m tapping over and over again – nothing happens. I can check other cells, the second, the third etc. and only after that I can check the first cell. This is my method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    NSUInteger oldRow = lastIndexPath.row;
    if (oldRow != row) {
        UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath];
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        lastIndexPath = indexPath;
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Or maybe you can advise other way to make it (checking only one cell in tableview), because I've found only models with a lot of code and hard to understand.

Comment: Are you initialising the lastIndexPath in your viewDidLoad?

Comment: What is your issue exactly??

Comment: He can't select first row, without selecting some other row.

Comment: Can you try if(indexPath!=lastIndexPath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because at first your `lastIndexPath` variable is `nil`, so `lastIndexPath.row` will return 0. If you tap on the first row, that row is also 0, so it won't enter the `if` statement. Replace that statement with: `if (!lastIndexPath || oldRow != row)`

Comment: Can you help me again? Checking only one cell works, but now I need opportunity to uncheck cell and leave the whole tableview unchecked. I thought that `else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}` will work but it doesn't.

Comment: Post the entire method

Comment: I've found the solution                                      `BOOL isSelected = (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone);                                                ……………… else if (oldRow == row) {
                cell.accessoryType = isSelected ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            }`
But when I save `cell.textlabel.text` in plist, save the "state" of cell (its checkmark) and then I load it into my tableview – the selection don't work properly. So maybe I should post it into next question. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell;
    //cell creation code
    cell.accessoryType = nil != lastIndexPath && lastIndexPath.row == indexPath.row ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray* reloadRows = nil == lastIndexPath ? @[indexPath] : @[lastIndexPath, indexPath];
    lastIndexPath = indexPath;
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:reloadRows withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```